# Need help- Documentation for non-technical people using Agile

Tags: scrum, agile, ms-project, pm-software

Now we are using Agile and hardly create BRD\FRD, we create user stories, and all this is good for everyone working in the same department. Including the stakeholders. However, if I would like to share the requirements with a person in any other department, who has not heard of Agile. How can convey what the product will do? I can give a demo; however, I can tell the rules and however, they might not remember all, and won’t be able to refer to something substantial. If I write on a document and read it to them with details. Here, I don’t like the idea of reading from a document because it gets boring. Also, I could add pictures to it and make it little interesting. However, for this I will need to go through user stories and create a document, this I don’t think is the best way. So, please guide me how can I solve the problem of sharing the details of a project(Requirements, limitations, etc) to a non-technical person. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Agile teams create a good amount of documentation (many of them do at least). However, it has a tendency to be more specific to its purpose. In the scenario you are facing, what is the goal you are trying to accomplish with the documentation? Also, User Stories usually make terrible documentation, which I why you find them inadequate. That's not really what they're for.

Comment: What did you do before agile? You didn't just drop a binder with the BRD/FRD on peoples tables, did you? Why can't you do the same you did before?

Comment: There are lots of ways to send your messages. See below...

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

There is no silver bullet. However, it is likely that your organization needs to adopt a more comprehensive set of agile tools and practices to reduce unnecessary or burdensome documentation.

### Agile Practices Often Deliver *Better* Documentation

Your question is possibly too broad to answer, but I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your organization has recently transitioned to "Agile" (whatever the organization thinks that means) without having actually adopted the complete framework, or without implementing common agile practices like Test-Driven Design (TDD) or Behavior-Driven Development (BDD). This is likely the source of your problem.

Agile frameworks value working products over extensive documentation. The Agile Manifesto says:

> Working software over comprehensive documentation...[T]here is value in the items on the right, [but] we value the items on the left more.

This doesn't mean agile teams don't document anything. In fact, high-performing agile and DevOps teams often produce *more* useful documentation than they did before adopting agile practices. This is generally because:

1. "Living documentation," like well-commented and frequently refactored code, is often more accurate than dead-tree hieroglyphics from the misty dawn of time when the initial requirements were most likely generated.
2. When properly-written, TDD/BDD/ATDD tests read like natural-language documentation, and often incorporate terms and concepts from the the product's business domain and a user's point of view.
3. Continuous integration using good tests ensures that your documentation remains both *current* and *accurate*, which is something that most traditional projects fail miserably at.
4. End-user or system documentation (if and when actually needed) is often compiled programmatically from code comments, executable tests, API signatures, and so forth. *Note: This requires both good practices and good tools.*
5. Any *necessary* documentation that isn't self-generating should be part of the Definition of Done for each Product Backlog Item (PBI) and the iteration's Increment.

In Scrum, you should have demonstrable increments of work every iteration. This is often more valuable than dead trees, because it represents a potentially-shippable increment and something the stakeholders can see (and often touch).

Maximize the amount of work *not* done by eliminating unnecessary documentation, and focus on implementing the practices that reduce truly essential documentation tasks to manageable proportions.

Answer (score 2):

FRD is a way to document (in a waterfall way) what the *intended* functional requirements are. This doesn't usually document *actual* implementation. Using agile methods, you can better communicate to non-technical staff what is actually being delivered. Here are some suggestions to allow for comprehensive documentation while staying agile and productive:

1. Have the technical writers be a part of the project team, creating
   technical and non-technical product documentation iteratively. You
   can add "product documentation completed" as acceptance criteria for your user
   stories. The official product documentation can be your living document.
2. Hold a pre-launch high level demo (via your product manager). This high level demo can help marketing, sales, and department managers understand what is being delivered. You could add this to your sprint review processes.
3. Add more in-depth internal training considerations to your launch
   delivery checklist so you can consider it for each sprint or release. You can flag epics or stories as requiring internal training and who should be responsible for performing the training.
4. Hold more detailed internal trainings (i.e., train the trainer) for interested
   internal stakeholders (such as customer support and trainers).
   Record these and have the video available for those who are
   interested to reference. Add a link of the video to your project reference
   documentation. The internal training can be very helpful to identify trends in questions that you may want to answer within the official product documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat I can think of 3 ways to communicate outcomes and requirements:

1. Invite **Stakeholders** to **Sprint Review** or maybe **Daily Stand Up**
2. Show **Stakeholders** your product's **Information Radiators**
3. Update the **Product**'s wiki/Slack channel:

   - Have an overview of the **Product**'s outcomes/KPI/requirements known from the start (with slides or any other documentation)
   - Focus overviews on delivering **Value** (gaining: $/user info/etc and reducing: costs) and share as needed
   - Have **Team Members** add additional detail and overviews of **Features** as the **Product** evolves and new info emerges

If Agile is new to your culture make sure that **Stakeholder** communication goes through the **Product Owner** and/or the **Scrum Master**. Those 2 roles will ensure the **Dev Team** is not derailed by outsiders.
Good luck!

Comment: Be careful inviting stakeholders to the daily scrum. That's technically for (and by) developers only and anyone visiting needs to be well aware of the "shut your mouth" rule.

Comment: Whilst well meaning, this answer is a stock response and does not answer the OP's question.  How does "Focus on delivering value" help the OP?  That is a generic mantra.

Comment: @Venture2099 My guards go up when I see "generic mantras" in these forums too. The OP's call to action was: "please guide me how can I solve the problem of sharing the details of a project (requirements, limitations, etc) to a non-technical person". Engaging non-techs with documents they won't read or understand is a waste of resources. Why not just get them involved in the process through the ceremonies (with Scrum Master supervision)? PS: this is a common problem so a "generic" answer may be a good one.